# Почему после каждого кода на C мы должны писать точку с запятой?

Tags: c++, c, синтаксис, дизайн-языка, грамматика

Почему после каждого кода на языке программирование C мы должны писать точку с запятой (`;`)? Я знаю, что это для того, чтобы код правильно работал, но как это работает?

Comment: Ну как-то надо же отделять друг от друга коды. Можно было бы и другой значок придумать, например "᧟", но точка с заяпятой показалась создателям языка подходящей.

Comment: Ну вот так сложилось исторически:) Можно было бы без этого, но как бы вы тогда понимали окончание команды? В Python, например, точки с запятой не обязательны

Comment: апочемупослекаждогослованарусскоммыдолжныставитьпробел?

Comment: А зачем мы на русском языке в конце каждого предложения ставим знак, завершающий предложение? Ответ прост: по правилам языка каждое предложение должно быть завершено одним из предназначенных для этого знаков. На заголовки не кивать, они не настоящие предложения. На бейсике инструкция завершается в конце строки, поэтому там двоеточие не нужно, но если в одной строке несколько инструкций, то их надо разделить двоеточием.

Comment: Но си – не бейсик, он позволяет всю программу в один столбец написать. И завершающий знак надо поставить даже в том случае, если конец инструкции или декларации попадает на конец строки. Но заголовки выделены точно также: в них точка с запятой не ставится. И именно этим заголовок функции отличается от её предварительной декларации: в предварительной декларации точка с запятой есть, а в заголовке её нет.

Answer (score 8):

На самом деле ничего волшебного или особенного в точке с запятой нет. Она ни чем не лучше и не хуже любого другого символа в исходном коде.

Другое дело, что конкретные правила употребления того или иного символа определяются [*грамматикой*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) языка. Грамматика языка C устроена так, что требует использования точки с запятой в конце *объявления* (англ. *declaration*), в конце объявления структуры (англ. *struct declaration*), в конце *expression statement*, в конце *jump statement*, а также в конце `do` `while` и внутри `for`:

> ```c
> (6.7) declaration:
>          declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
>
> (6.7.2.1) struct-declaration:
>              specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-list ;
>
> (6.8.3) expression-statement:
>            expressionopt ;
>
> (6.8.5) iteration-statement:
>            while ( expression ) statement
>            do statement while ( expression ) ;
>            for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
>            for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
>
> (6.8.6) jump-statement:
>            goto identifier ;
>            continue ;
>            break ;
>            return expressionopt ;
> ```
>
> — Отрывок из ISO/IEC 9899:1999 Appendix A.

---

Использование точки с запятой не является каким-то обязательным требованием. Главное, чтобы грамматика языка не была *неоднозначной* (англ. [ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar)).

Один из классических примеров неоднозначной конструкции в языках программирования — это «[висячий `else`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else)»:

```c
/* К какому if относится этот else? */
if (a) if (b) s1; else s2;
```

Для решения этой неоднозначности можно ввести ключевое слово `fi` (так сделано в Bash); дополнительные `begin` и `end` (Pascal); или требовать, чтобы `else` относился к ближайшему `if`<sup>‡</sup> — так сделано в C.

Точно также точка с запятой просто является инструментом для решения различных неоднозначностей в языке C, которые проявились бы, если бы этой точки с запятой не было.

---

† <sup>Во многих других языках программирования точка с запятой, хоть и входит в грамматику, но не является обязательной для использования и может быть опущена в некоторых контекстах. В Go, например, лексический анализатор в большинстве случаев [сам вставляет точку с запятой](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#semicolons) в конце каждой строки. (*Кстати, это одна из причин, почему в Go нельзя переносить фигурную скобку `{` на новую строку*.)</sup>

‡ <sup>Этого будет достаточно в плане семантики, но чтобы избавится от неоднозначности грамматики потребуются дополнительные `{` и `}`.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Одной из особенностей языка С является компактность синтаксиса, позволяющая экономить байты, используемые для хранения исходного кода. В свое время это было одним из факторов, помогавших С набирать популярность. Однако помимо ухудшения читабельности, многие синтаксические конструкции получились неоднозначными без привлечения дополнительных разделителей. Например

```
int x = 3;
int y = 5;
int z = x;
++y -= 2;
```

без разделителей выглядит как

```
int x = 3
int y = 5
int z = x
++y -= 2
```

делая невозможным отличить от

```
int x = 3
int y = 5
int z = x++
y -= 2
```

Comment: Можно добавить, что разные языки несут в себе некие "следы оптимизации", которые были важны на раннем этапе развития языка. Например, в PHP использование знака $ перед именем переменной объясняется тем, что в самых первых версиях так было проще построить синтакисческий разбор. А вот вопрос на засыпку: в каком (экзотическом) языке в именах переменных допустимы пробелы? я когда то читал про него, но название забыл... (не whitespace, нет :-) )

Comment: @S.H. В powershell например. Хотя это совсем не экзотический язык.

Comment: В php перед переменными ставится символ $, потому что все взяли с perl

Comment: @KoVadim А почему именно с perl, а не с shell например?

Comment: По моему, в powershell надо имя такой переменной при её определени брать в кавычки.  А я читал про язычок, где этого делать не надо.

Comment: @S.H. FORTRAN еще допускал использование пробелов в именах переменных и вообще где угодно за счет полного игнорирования пробелов.

Comment: @user7860670 - забавно, но нет, это было что то из современных...

Comment: @user7860670 потому что вначале php был шаблонизатором, написаном на perl. А вот где Perl взял свои доллары... видимо с awk.

Comment: Почему же невозможно? Перенос строки есть, значит уже другая инструкция.

Comment: @Эникейщик А перенос строки не является разделителем для выражений. И в С его не так-то просто было бы превратить в разделитель, так как при этом поломался бы препроцессор.

Comment: @user7860670, а что не так с препроцессором?

Comment: @Qwertiy Честно говоря, я уже не помню, что я тогда имел ввиду. Однако можно предположить, что если бы разделителем был перенос строки, а не точка с запятой, то было бы нельзя сделать define с более, чем одним выражением.

Comment: @user7860670, да, понял, логично.